# String comparison in ksh never succeeding

Tags: variables, comparison, ksh

I have the next script, and when trying to compare variable value if equals "NO" or "SI" (yes in spanish) it's not working for some reason I keep going all the time through the else (SI) although the real value in the variable is "NO". It's even being printed in the email subject.

I fear I could be some extra invisible character I can't see but it's there?

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

VAR=$(/home/userName/scripts/loadedresource.ksh | egrep 'SI|NO')

MAIL_FILE="testfile.txt"

rm -f $MAIL_FILE

echo "From:Script" > $MAIL_FILE
echo "To:Me<me@company.com>" >> $MAIL_FILE
echo "Subject:RESOURCE LOADED-> $VAR" >> $MAIL_FILE
echo "Content-Type: text/html" >> $MAIL_FILE
echo "<html>" >> $MAIL_FILE
echo "<body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14px;'>" >> $MAIL_FILE


if [ "$VAR" == "NO" ]
then
    echo "<h2> Resource not loaded, please open ticket </h2>" >> $MAIL_FILE
else
    echo "<h2> Resource loaded successfully </h2>" >> $MAIL_FILE
fi

mail me@company.com < $MAIL_FILE
```

Comment: Use `ksh -x yourscript` to see what's actually going on during execution. There are many different implementations of ksh, so it's hard to give an answer that's guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: ...also, using `set -x` for debugging will correctly inform you as to any hidden characters.

Comment: Also, don't use `>>$MAIL_FILE` once per line -- that's extremely inefficient (it reopens the file for every single echo).

Comment: Also, don't use all-uppercase variable names for locals in shell; by convention, these names are reserved for environment variables and builtins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is not a valid comparison operator in POSIX test. If your particular implementation of ksh doesn't implement an extension adding it, you may need to use

```
if [ "$VAR" = "NO" ]
```

rather than

```
if [ "$VAR" == "NO" ]
```

---

I'd also consider using `egrep -o 'SI|NO'` to leave out any other characters from the output of `grep`, if your copy has GNU extensions.

---

As another option, consider:

```
result=$(/home/userName/scripts/loadedresource.ksh)
case $result in
  *SI*) echo "Yes" ;;
  *NO*) echo "No" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown" ;;
esac
```

---

As a performance enhancement, by the way:

```
{
  echo "hello"
  echo "world"
} >output.txt
```

...is considerably more efficient than

```
echo "hello" >output.txt
echo "world" >>output.txt
```

...which re-opens the output file once for each line.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on improving the efficency, i have just applied these changes. After doing it it keeps not comparing right, my egrep implementation doen't admit -o as an option, it just admits (from man egrep) : -b -c -e -f -h -i -l -n -s -v and -x

Comment: Do you know if your version of ksh supports `[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]`?

Comment: @wagger, ...actually, I added another option, using the `case` builtin and not relying on `grep` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on improving the efficency, i have just applied these changes. After doing it it keeps not comparing right, my egrep implementation doen't admit -o as an option, it just admits (from man egrep) : -b -c -e -f -h -i -l -n -s -v and -x

From doing an execution with ksh -x scriptname, i get the next result, im not sure if there is another character being added after "NO":

+ echo <body style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14px;'>
 = NO ]
+ echo <h2> Resource loaded successfully! </h2>

Comment: @wagger, ...yes, replacing grep with the case statement shown should work.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks a million, it's working now using the "case". YOu can't imagine how many options i have tried before :))) How on earth could this happen :S . Thanks again!!!